# agregar un atributo a un input con una función

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

buenas lo que estoy haciendo es poner un rango de fechas con jquery, se que se puede hacer con moment js pero quería intentarlo de otra manera, en fin todo el procedimiento lo hace bien solo que al momento de agregar el max="0000-00-00" en el date el input no lo toma aquí está mi código:

```
$("#fechaINICIO").change(function(){
var fechai = new Date($('#fechaINICIO').val());
var dias = 8;
fechai.setDate(fechai.getDate() + dias);
var fechamaxima = fechai.innerText =  ('0' + fechai.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (fechai.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + fechai.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("fechafinal").setAttribute("max", fechamaxima);
console.log(fechamaxima);
});
```

y aquí está el input :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Fin</label>
<input type="date" max="" id="fechafinal" name="to_date" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

¿tendría que especificarle de alguna manera que es un tipo de dato o que será lo que falla ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona, el tema es que la fecha tiene que ir en formato UTC, ej: 2012-01-01T11:57Z

O sea tienes que dar vuelta fechamaxima

```js
$("#fechaINICIO").change(function(){
var fechai = new Date($('#fechaINICIO').val());
var dias = 8;
fechai.setDate(fechai.getDate() + dias);
    var fechamaxima = fechai.innerText = fechai.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (fechai.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + fechai.getDate()).slice(-2);
document.getElementById("fechafinal").setAttribute("max", fechamaxima);
console.log(fechamaxima);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" max="" id="fechaINICIO" name="to_date" class="form-control" required>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Fin</label>
<input type="date" max="" id="fechafinal" name="to_date" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: si, justo lo note muchas gracias